# Pass variable from controller to another controller via rootScope

Tags: angularjs

im working on a project, and I'm having difficulties passing a variable from a `MainController` to `NavbarController`, via `rootScope`.

> Angular doesnt print the {{windowName}} variable that i pass from MainController to NavbarController via $rootScope.

So this is the code that im using:

View:

```
<body>
  <nav ng-controller="NavbarController">
    <ul>
      <li>{{windowName}}</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- this is where i use ng-view instead of MainController -->
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{name}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MainController($scope, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.windowName = 'Window name 95';

  $scope.name = 'Test name';
}

function NavbarController($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.windowName = $rootScope.windowName;
}
```

Filddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6v0fx6d2/1/

Explanation:

I'm using ngRoute, so i simplified the code, in the comment is where i use ng-view, to render the templates, so the navbar is the Basic Template that I'm using.

Comment: All info of $scope.apply is found [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you change your html structure it will work.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{name}}
  </div>
  <nav ng-controller="NavbarController">
    <ul>
      <li>{{windowName}}</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

In angularjs the controllers are executed in the order they appear in the code.So in your case the windowName is not set. So it isn't available in NavbarController

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the problem.

To print a rootScope variable you need to add {{$route.windowName}} .

> Also if  you use ExpressJS with HoganTemplate, make sure you change
>   Hogan mustache brackets with this:
>
> `app.locals.delimiters = '{{{ }}}';`